# Critical error 41 Kernel-Power in the Event viewer no BSoD

Tags: boot, power-supply, crash

Troubleshooting Help:

```
Corsair Vengeance LPX (2x, 8GB, DDR4-3000, DIMM 288)
MSI GTX 970 Gaming 4G (4GB, Midrange)
WD Blue (500GB, 2.5", Notebook)
Corsair H55 (5.20cm)
Gigabyte GA-Z170MX-Gaming 5 (LGA 1151, Intel Z170, mATX)
Corsair CS750M (750W)
Intel Core i7 6700K BOX (LGA 1151, 4GHz, Unlocked)
Samsung 850 Pro (256GB, 2.5")
```

Critical error 41 Kernel-Power in the Event viewer meaning my Windows restarted without properly shutting down. This happens every 1-2 hour, no blue screen just a restart of my PC without shutting down, looks like loss of power.

Reset my Windows, it is a clean install now. Used Benchmark tool from Tomb Raider on ultra high to test wether the GPU draws too much power and to observe the temperature: doesn't go over 60°C, starts spinning.

Opened the case and removed some dust from the fans, there were a lot of dust particles accumulated at the bottom of the case in the filter, cleaned it.

- checked fast boot option (was disabled already in bios) and disabled the windows one
- checked both memory stick
- sadly i don't have another PSU but it seems a legit problem...
- i don't have a multimeter, maybe i'll buy one
- PSU doesn't feel hot either when it forcefully restarts

** if you could direct me towards better troubleshooting methods, i'd appreciate your help, thanks in advance **

Comment: These are very difficult to diagnose, but are almost always hardware related. I would start with a known good PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my computer currently runs 15 hours without a restart. The problem seemed to be a loose 8V connector on the motherboard behind the CPU fan :/ check all your connectors guys

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason for the "Kernel Power 41" error in the Windows Event Log was the video card.
My laptop (Lenovo Flex 2-15 Pro) turned off randomly after 20-30 minutes without any notice.

I had updated all drivers before.
But Windows Update seems to distribute a wrong driver for some NVIDIA video cards, as I read on https://www.computerbase.de/forum/threads/nach-neusten-treiber-installation-kernel-power-41.1703758/

After I deactived the NVIDIA video card, the problem did not appear any more:

[image]

I will now see how I can permanently fix the problem. I will probably re-install the original driver again and prevent driver updates for the video card.